# I have an error while customizing my default next config js file . I have tried in multiple ways but it always throws an error that invalid src prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, config

> As you can see that I want to add my custom configuration in
> **next.config.js** . But it throws and error of **invalid src prop** . I have tried this in multiple ways but it always throws an error.

```
// Default Configuration
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: false,
      swcMinify: true,
      image: {
        domains: ["links.papareact.com", "image.tmdb.org"],
      },
    };
    
    module.exports = nextConfig;
    
    //Configuration I want to add in this file
    module.exports = {
      images: {
        domains: ["links.papareact.com", "image.tmdb.org"],
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. The first export ist correct, you just have a typo. But you are defining the export again. You can just have one module.exports:

```js
// Default Configuration
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["links.papareact.com", "image.tmdb.org"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Note its images not image. You might want to checkout the loader configuration: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loader for images here

```
    const myLoader=({src})=>{
     return `${path}`;
    }
```

src, in that case, is what you add in config

```
<Image loader={myLoader} ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).